# Cannot flag as duplicate if there are no upvoted or accepted answers

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have found OP1 (from 2019)
[How to Set Different Layouts for 2 Keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107447/how-to-set-different-layouts-for-2-keyboards)
and OP2
[Can I Set Different Languages to 2 Keyboards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353786/can-i-set-different-languages-to-2-keyboards)
(recent), which is an obvious dupe of OP1.

I mean to flag OP1 as a dupe, but I get a "greyed out" Vote to close button
[image]

So, the fact that an original question does not have any upvoted or accepted answer precludes others being flagged as dupes.
I don't see the rationale for this. The nature of a dupe would not depend on the answers, I guess.

**1. Can someone explain the rationale?**

Note 1:
OP2 seems in turn a dupe of the linked OP3 [Xsetkbmap, odd behaviour using the device option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465488/xsetkbmap-odd-behaviour-using-the-device-option), as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465488/xsetkbmap-odd-behaviour-using-the-device-option#comment1827234_465488).

Note 2:
I found a few questions Q1, Q2, ..., related to this one in Meta, but if I understand correctly they do not ask the same as I am asking here. Moreover, they seem to imply that the OPs of Q1, ..., do not see the limitation I am seeing

1. [Flagging Duplicate questions when answers are not accepted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3792/flagging-duplicate-questions-when-answers-are-not-accepted)
2. [Should a question be flagged as duplicate even if the question (older) pointed to as the duplicate has no answers?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3854/should-a-question-be-flagged-as-duplicate-even-if-the-question-older-pointed-t)
3. [Are we doing anything differently with duplicates when there is no answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5961/are-we-doing-anything-differently-with-duplicates-when-there-is-no-answer)

**2. Can someone explain why these other people can apparently flag dupes under conditions I cannot?**

PS:
4. [What should I do If I can't flag as duplicate because answer is neither accepted nor upvoted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12212/what-should-i-do-if-i-cant-flag-as-duplicate-because-answer-is-neither-accepted)
sees the same limitation as I do.

Comment: AFAIK the rationale behind this limitation is because, if a question has an upvoted or accepted answer then it will be useful to the OP of the question being closed and likely provide them with an answer to their question. I think this is just a hold over from when SE was much smaller, the current volume of questions here makes it seem a bit counter intuitive. I can't seem to find a source for this but I am sure I have read about it in the past, if I find anything, I will post it.

Comment: These links might be helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928

Comment: In https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12212/what-should-i-do-if-i-cant-flag-as-duplicate-because-answer-is-neither-accepted , OP sees the same limitation you do.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to links in comments I can answer question 2.

**The Beginning**.
1 In the beginning Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky created Stackoverflow.
2 And they said, “Let there be dupe flagging,” and any question could be flagged as a dupe...

As per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question), dated [*Feb 2 '13 at 0:07*] "Today, the behavior of duplicate close votes was changed so that a question can only be a duplicate close vote target if it has an upvoted or accepted answer", also confirmed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate), dated [*Feb 2 '13 at 0:29*].

That is why

1. [Flagging Duplicate questions when answers are not accepted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3792/flagging-duplicate-questions-when-answers-are-not-accepted) [*Jul 30 '12 at 10:54*]
2. [Should a question be flagged as duplicate even if the question (older) pointed to as the duplicate has no answers?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3854/should-a-question-be-flagged-as-duplicate-even-if-the-question-older-pointed-t) [*Aug 7 '12 at 12:52*]
3. [Are we doing anything differently with duplicates when there is no answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5961/are-we-doing-anything-differently-with-duplicates-when-there-is-no-answer) [*Feb 1 '13 at 10:38*]... **This one was asked the day before the change, did it influence in any way the decision for a change?**

do not see the limitation, and

4. [What should I do If I can't flag as duplicate because answer is neither accepted nor upvoted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12212/what-should-i-do-if-i-cant-flag-as-duplicate-because-answer-is-neither-accepted) [*Nov 5 '14 at 17:32*]

does.

**Related**:

[Prevent Closing as duplicate when the duplicate has no accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133955/prevent-closing-as-duplicate-when-the-duplicate-has-no-accepted-answer)